# Symfony throws error 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, symfony1, symfony-1.2

I have a module with the name **evaulation_symptom**, and I'm trying to create new symptom but when i click on new(*evaluation_symptom/new*) it throws the below error:

> 500 | Internal Server Error | PropelException [wrapped:
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   '=evaluation_symptom.ID ORDER BY evaluation_symptom.ORD
>   ASC,evaluation_cause.ORD ' at line 1]

I studied the code and what i noticed is that all problem lies in the **EvaluationSymptomAdminPeer** function called ***getUbferredRemediesBySymptomId*** and specially this line **$criteria->addJoin(self::ID, $id);**

```
public static function getInferredRemediesBySymptomId($id)
  {
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("evaluation_remedy.ID");
    $criteria->addSelectColumn("evaluation_remedy.TITLE");

    $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, EvaluationSymptomCausePeer::EVALUATION_SYMPTOM_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(EvaluationSymptomCausePeer::EVALUATION_CAUSE_ID, EvaluationCausePeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(EvaluationCausePeer::ID, EvaluationCauseRemedyPeer::EVALUATION_CAUSE_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(EvaluationCauseRemedyPeer::EVALUATION_REMEDY_ID, EvaluationRemedyPeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, $id);

    $exCriteria = $criteria->getNewCriterion(self::IS_ACTIVE, 1);
    $exCriteria->addOr($criteria->getNewCriterion(EvaluationCausePeer::IS_ACTIVE, 1));
    $criteria->add($exCriteria);
    //$criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn(self::ORD);
    //$criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn(EvaluationCausePeer::ORD);
    $criteria->addAscendingOrderByColumn(self::ORD)->addAscendingOrderByColumn(EvaluationCausePeer::ORD);
    $records = self::doSelectStmt($criteria)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $data = array();
    foreach ($records as $key => $record) {
      $data[$record['ID']] = $record['TITLE'];
    }
    return $data;
  }
```

ID to the above function is passed from **EvaluationSymptomAdminForm** as :

```
$inferredRemedies = EvaluationSymptomAdminPeer::getInferredRemediesBySymptomId($this->object->getPrimaryKey());
```

Comment: Print the whole query and validate the query.

Comment: How @UmairShahYousafzai the query is validated only the ID part isn't working! When i comment this line $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, $id); everything goes smooth but when i add it back it isn't working.

Comment: You need to have a print on the whole query along the ID and then see for yourself where do you have the error in the query.

Comment: Check your symfony log files that will contain the query in full.